# Remove arrow icon from expendable card view android

Tags: java, android

I am using https://github.com/AleSpero/ExpandableCardView  library to make an expendable card view. But i don't need the arrow placed in right side.

I also try to find for the attribute or method that can remove this but don't find any one. Please help me to solve this. I will be very grateful. Thanks in advance for your time.

```java
card.setIcon(null);
```

but it remove only the left icon not the right icon.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line`android:groupIndicator="@null"`

```
<ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/ev_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="188dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:groupIndicator="@null" />
```

Answer (score 0):

On your MainActivity please use below code

```
val card : ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.card_arrow)
        card.visibility=View.INVISIBL
```

or remove icon from this xml file expandable_cardview

```
 <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/card_arrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                              android:contentDescription="@string/expandable_card_view_image_content_description"/>
```